# Does the service command work in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, restart, systemd

The manpage for the service command in 15.04 says that it is for running a System V init script, although under DESCRIPTION, it says that it can also be used for an upstart job. It is my understanding that 15.04 uses neither of these, but systemd instead. So does service still work as before, or is there a new way for doing things like restarting a server under systemd?

Answer (score 1):

`service` in Ubuntu works with systemd, Upstart and SysV init so you don't have to care which kind of init configuration is used.

Comment: I filed a bug report for that: [#1452850](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1452850)